# how to count no of times a variable is in a array in javascript in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

hi guys i am trying to create a like system where when users like a post it gets saved in the database that this user has liked this post now i need to count the no of times 'like' has been done.now i used a column type to save the like whenever someone click but when i am retrieving how many likes are on a post how can i count how many likes has been done on this post.here is my code

**script**

```
function select_likes(post_id)
{
  var Post_id=post_id;
  var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
  jQuery.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'<?php echo base_url("user/select_likes"); ?>',
                  data: {Post_id:Post_id,User_id:User_id},
                  dataType: 'json', 
                   success:function(data)
                  {
                    var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                         var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

                         $.each(json, function (key, data) {
                          var likes=data.type;
                     // alert(likes);
                          var count=likes.length;
                          alert(count);
                //           var post_id=data.post_id;
                //           $post_id=post_id;
                //           // alert(comment);
                //            // // alert(post_id);
                //            // var      div_list=document.getElementById('#comment_div').innerHTML='post_id;
                //           // $("#comment_post_id").attr('value',$post_id);
                           var mediaID ='.likes'+post_id;
                             $(mediaID).append(likes); 
                  });
                }
          });
}
```

**controller**

```
public function select_likes()
{
  $Post_id=$this->input->post('Post_id');
  $User_id=$this->input->post('User_id');

  $this->load->model('Pmodel');
  $select_likes=$this->Pmodel->select_likes_post_id($Post_id,$User_id);
  // print_r($select_likes);
  echo json_encode($select_likes);
}
```

**model**

```
public function select_likes_post_id($Post_id,$User_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('userpost_likes_share');
    $this->db->where('post_id',$Post_id);    
    $this->db->where('type','like');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $likes=$query->result_array();

    return $likes;
}
```

but how can i count it ? is it possible to count no of times a variable calls in javscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `count()` function on `$select_likes` in controller  `count($select_likes)` ... it will be the number of like on the post and pass it as `json` as `json_encode(array('like_count'=>$like_count))`

So in controller code can be like:

```
public function select_likes()
{
 $Post_id=$this->input->post('Post_id');
  $User_id=$this->input->post('User_id');

  $this->load->model('Pmodel');
  $select_likes=$this->Pmodel->select_likes_post_id($Post_id,$User_id);
  $like_count = count($select_likes);
  echo json_encode(array('like_count'=>$like_count));
}
```

Use in js script you can use the `data.like_count` as total number of like on the post.

If you only need like count from table then i would suggest only select one column from your 'userpost_likes_share' table.. you can select only id(primary key) of the table for make the code work faster.

Let me know if you think i get wrong and answer in wrong direction...